# Load CustomView class inside mainclass in Xml

Tags: android, view

I try to load the customview class that is inside my mainclass in xml. Because to save the image in view i create buttons in the xml, i need to load these customview in framelayout of my xml. By start these i simply put the view class in linear Layout, It cause forceclose :(

My MainClass.java

```
public class FingerPaint extends Activity
    implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {    
int height,width;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
    height = display.getHeight();   
    Log.i("FingerPaint", ""+width+""+height);
    //setContentView(new MyView(this));--->It Works fine. But need these in xml
    setContentView(R.layout.paint);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

    mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },
                                   0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

    mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
}

private Paint       mPaint;
private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
private MaskFilter  mBlur;

public void colorChanged(int color) {
    mPaint.setColor(color);
}

public class MyView extends View {

    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/angel.jpg");
        if (bm != null) {
            setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bm));
            Log.i("FingerPaint", "setbackground"+bm.getHeight());
        }
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
   }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       // canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

private static final int COLOR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int EMBOSS_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private static final int BLUR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
private static final int ERASE_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
private static final int SRCATOP_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, COLOR_MENU_ID, 0, "Color").setShortcut('3', 'c');
    menu.add(0, EMBOSS_MENU_ID, 0, "Emboss").setShortcut('4', 's');
    menu.add(0, BLUR_MENU_ID, 0, "Blur").setShortcut('5', 'z');
    menu.add(0, ERASE_MENU_ID, 0, "Erase").setShortcut('5', 'z');
    menu.add(0, SRCATOP_MENU_ID, 0, "SrcATop").setShortcut('5', 'z');

    /****   Is this the mechanism to extend with filter effects?
    Intent intent = new Intent(null, getIntent().getData());
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    menu.addIntentOptions(
                          Menu.ALTERNATIVE, 0,
                          new ComponentName(this, NotesList.class),
                          null, intent, 0, null);
    *****/
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
    mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case COLOR_MENU_ID:
            new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
            return true;
        case EMBOSS_MENU_ID:
            if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mEmboss) {
                mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
            } else {
                mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
            }
            return true;
        case BLUR_MENU_ID:
            if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mBlur) {
                mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
            } else {
                mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
            }
            return true;
        case ERASE_MENU_ID:
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            /*//mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC)); 
            mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);*/
            return true;
        case SRCATOP_MENU_ID:
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
            mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And paint.xml as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <com.powercamerapro.FingerPaint.MyView android:id="@+id/myView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     </com.powercamerapro.FingerPaint.MyView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

It throws Exception,

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(670): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.powercamerapro.FingerPaint.MyView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e8c840
```

Kindly point out my mistake and how to be correct these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this for inner class com.powercamerapro.FingerPaint$MyView

and use `<view class="com.powercamerapro.FingerPaint$MyView" />`
+

```
You need to add public static to the inner class
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But it just shows the blank page when use the above code in xml

Comment: No. Now i correct that by putting the view class as separete.